# twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: 111: Connection refused

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, pycharm

I'm getting the following failure:-

> Failure: twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was
>   refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.

I note that the client never asks me for a password. I'm running it from inside PyCharm.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My client code is:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

from twisted.conch.ssh import transport, userauth, connection, common, keys, channel
from twisted.internet import defer, protocol, reactor
from twisted.python import log
import struct, sys, getpass, os

USER = 'user'
HOST = 'localhost'

class SimpleTransport(transport.SSHClientTransport):
    def verifyHostKey(self, hostKey, fingerprint):
        print 'host key fingerprint: %s' % fingerprint
        return defer.succeed(1) 

    def connectionSecure(self):
        self.requestService(
            SimpleUserAuth(USER,
                SimpleConnection()))

class SimpleUserAuth(userauth.SSHUserAuthClient):
    def getPassword(self):
        return defer.succeed(getpass.getpass("password" % (USER, HOST)))

    def getGenericAnswers(self, name, instruction, questions):
        print name
        print instruction
        answers = []
        for prompt, echo in questions:
            if echo:
                answer = raw_input(prompt)
            else:
                answer = getpass.getpass(prompt)
            answers.append(answer)
        return defer.succeed(answers)

    def getPublicKey(self):
        path = os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_dsa') 
        # this works with rsa too
        # just change the name here and in getPrivateKey
        if not os.path.exists(path) or self.lastPublicKey:
            # the file doesn't exist, or we've tried a public key
            return
        return keys.Key.fromFile(filename=path+'.pub').blob()

    def getPrivateKey(self):
        path = os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_dsa')
        return defer.succeed(keys.Key.fromFile(path).keyObject)

class SimpleConnection(connection.SSHConnection):
    def serviceStarted(self):
        self.openChannel(TrueChannel(2**16, 2**15, self))
        self.openChannel(FalseChannel(2**16, 2**15, self))
        self.openChannel(CatChannel(2**16, 2**15, self))

class TrueChannel(channel.SSHChannel):
    name = 'session' # needed for commands

    def openFailed(self, reason):
        print 'true failed', reason

    def channelOpen(self, ignoredData):
        self.conn.sendRequest(self, 'exec', common.NS('true'))

    def request_exit_status(self, data):
        status = struct.unpack('>L', data)[0]
        print 'true status was: %s' % status
        self.loseConnection()

class FalseChannel(channel.SSHChannel):
    name = 'session'

    def openFailed(self, reason):
        print 'false failed', reason

    def channelOpen(self, ignoredData):
        self.conn.sendRequest(self, 'exec', common.NS('false'))

    def request_exit_status(self, data):
        status = struct.unpack('>L', data)[0]
        print 'false status was: %s' % status
        self.loseConnection()

class CatChannel(channel.SSHChannel):
    name = 'session'

    def openFailed(self, reason):
        print 'echo failed', reason

    def channelOpen(self, ignoredData):
        self.data = ''
        d = self.conn.sendRequest(self, 'exec', common.NS('cat'), wantReply = 1)
        d.addCallback(self._cbRequest)

    def _cbRequest(self, ignored):
        self.write('hello conch\n')
        self.conn.sendEOF(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.data += data

    def closed(self):
        print 'got data from cat: %s' % repr(self.data)
        self.loseConnection()
        reactor.stop()

protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, SimpleTransport).connectTCP(HOST, 5022)
reactor.run()
```

and my server code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

from twisted.cred import portal, checkers
from twisted.conch import error, avatar
from twisted.conch.checkers import SSHPublicKeyDatabase
from twisted.conch.ssh import factory, userauth, connection, keys, session
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, defer
from twisted.python import log
from zope.interface import implements
import sys
log.startLogging(sys.stderr)

"""
Example of running another protocol over an SSH channel.
log in with username "user" and password "password".
"""

class ExampleAvatar(avatar.ConchUser):

    def __init__(self, username):
        avatar.ConchUser.__init__(self)
        self.username = username
        self.channelLookup.update({'session':session.SSHSession})

class ExampleRealm:
    implements(portal.IRealm)

    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        return interfaces[0], ExampleAvatar(avatarId), lambda: None

class EchoProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    """this is our example protocol that we will run over SSH
    """
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        if data == '\r':
            data = '\r\n'
        elif data == '\x03': #^C
            self.transport.loseConnection()
            return
        self.transport.write(data)

publicKey = 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAGEArzJx8OYOnJmzf4tfBEvLi8DVPrJ3/c9k2I/Az64fxjHf9imyRJbixtQhlH9lfNjUIx+4LmrJH5QNRsFporcHDKOTwTTYLh5KmRpslkYHRivcJSkbh/C+BR3utDS555mV'

privateKey = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""


class InMemoryPublicKeyChecker(SSHPublicKeyDatabase):

    def checkKey(self, credentials):
        return credentials.username == 'user' and \
            keys.Key.fromString(data=publicKey).blob() == credentials.blob

class ExampleSession:

    def __init__(self, avatar):
        """
        We don't use it, but the adapter is passed the avatar as its first
        argument.
        """

    def getPty(self, term, windowSize, attrs):
        pass

    def execCommand(self, proto, cmd):
        raise Exception("no executing commands")

    def openShell(self, trans):
        ep = EchoProtocol()
        ep.makeConnection(trans)
        trans.makeConnection(session.wrapProtocol(ep))

    def eofReceived(self):
        pass

    def closed(self):
        pass

from twisted.python import components
components.registerAdapter(ExampleSession, ExampleAvatar, session.ISession)

class ExampleFactory(factory.SSHFactory):
    publicKeys = {
        'ssh-rsa': keys.Key.fromString(data=publicKey)
    }
    privateKeys = {
        'ssh-rsa': keys.Key.fromString(data=privateKey)
    }
    services = {
        'ssh-userauth': userauth.SSHUserAuthServer,
        'ssh-connection': connection.SSHConnection
    }


portal = portal.Portal(ExampleRealm())
passwdDB = checkers.InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse()
passwdDB.addUser('user', 'password')
portal.registerChecker(passwdDB)
portal.registerChecker(InMemoryPublicKeyChecker())
ExampleFactory.portal = portal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.listenTCP(5022, ExampleFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: Try install and run the rabbitmq server for tcp connection